Flux groupBy and new traceId for every new portion of data
I want to implement reactive kafka consumer like that:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/[6.8. Concurrent Processing with Partition-Based Ordering
][1]
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newElastic("sample", 60, true);
KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
         .receive()
         .groupBy(m -> m.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
         .flatMap(partitionFlux ->
             partitionFlux.publishOn(scheduler)
                          .map(r -> processRecord(partitionFlux.key(), r))
                          .sample(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
                          .concatMap(offset -> offset.commit()));

And I want to trace every poll. The problem is that with groupBy I can have only one assignment of traceId per group just once.
I simplified code without kafka:
Flux
    .interval(Duration.ofMillis(100)) // kafka messages
    .filter {
        it % 2L == 0L // for simplicity, we will leave only one group
    }
    .groupBy {
        it % 2L
    }
//    .windowTimeout(2, Duration.ofMillis(10))
    .flatMap { group ->
        val traceId1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString() // for clarity, two traceId
        Flux.deferContextual {
            Mono.just(it.get<String>("traceId2")) //for clarity, two traceId
        }.flatMap { traceId2 ->
            group.bufferTimeout(2, Duration.ofMillis(10))
                .concatMap {
                    // here I handle my batch
                    Mono.just(it).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(50))
                }.flatMap {
                    // and here I will commit
                    println("$it - $traceId1 - $traceId2")
                    Mono.just(it)
                }
        }
            .contextWrite {
                it.put("traceId2", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            }
    }
    .blockLast()

and the output is:
[0] - d69da7b2-205b-4742-b538-308192af29d6 - 529c50a5-4966-4b52-bd63-18d4b879d8d4
[2] - d69da7b2-205b-4742-b538-308192af29d6 - 529c50a5-4966-4b52-bd63-18d4b879d8d4
[4] - d69da7b2-205b-4742-b538-308192af29d6 - 529c50a5-4966-4b52-bd63-18d4b879d8d4
[6] - d69da7b2-205b-4742-b538-308192af29d6 - 529c50a5-4966-4b52-bd63-18d4b879d8d4
[8] - d69da7b2-205b-4742-b538-308192af29d6 - 529c50a5-4966-4b52-bd63-18d4b879d8d4
[10] - d69da7b2-205b-4742-b538-308192af29d6 - 529c50a5-4966-4b52-bd63-18d4b879d8d4

The same traceId1 and the same traceId2.
But if we imagine that the grouping performing with windowTimeout - then everything will be fine:
Flux
    .interval(Duration.ofMillis(100)) // kafka messages
    .filter {
        it % 2L == 0L // for simplicity, we will leave only one group
    }
/*
    .groupBy {
        it % 2L
    }
*/
    .windowTimeout(2, Duration.ofMillis(10))
    .flatMap { group ->
        val traceId1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString() // for clarity, two traceId
        Flux.deferContextual {
            Mono.just(it.get<String>("traceId2")) //for clarity, two traceId
        }.flatMap { traceId2 ->
            group.bufferTimeout(2, Duration.ofMillis(10))
                .concatMap {
                    // here I handle my batch
                    Mono.just(it).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(50))
                }.flatMap {
                    // and here I will commit
                    println("$it - $traceId1 - $traceId2")
                    Mono.just(it)
                }
        }
            .contextWrite {
                it.put("traceId2", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            }
    }
    .blockLast()

and we have the following result:
[0] - d571b08e-d14c-425e-9062-49de555b6b6e - edef203f-4727-4b9b-bc27-82743e8c16f3
[2] - 8b1b2998-ff83-4b09-990c-93b3ad8e386b - e4b00092-e4b7-4f54-aa8a-90ac4882dea3
[4] - 323450bf-6d2c-4e39-8534-7d7ea63fbc31 - 1be0022c-88f4-4339-a00f-7e9f4f5ed45d
[6] - 8db7d902-5047-4772-9ebb-9b8bef983126 - ce92b804-ac72-4af1-b353-5c7576d71a01
[8] - 838e230c-fdb2-4e33-901e-96b7cbf2543e - f355382e-54ef-4a02-b2ed-a32bf855563c
[10] - d8bfc951-98a1-428a-b697-ebc447a78a40 - 916d2824-4e76-47fb-8573-653e954841eb

Different traceId1 and different traceId2.
How to acheive that using groupBy or maybe there is a replacement for groupBy in this case?

You gave two examples and they give a different result, but you it's unclear what you want to get and what's wrong with the given examples. What do you mean by "I want to trace every poll" and why none of the examples is acceptable?

@IgorArtamonov, The problem is that with groupBy I can have only one assignment of traceId per group just once.

We can use collectMultimap instead of groupBy:
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100)) // kafka messages
    .windowTimeout(10, Duration.ofMillis(1000)) // kafka batch
    .flatMap { polling ->
        polling.collectMultimap {
            it % 2
        }
            .flatMapMany { map ->
                map.keys
                    .map {
                        Flux.fromIterable(map[it]!!)
                    }
                    .let {
                        Flux.fromIterable(it)
                    }
            }
    }
    .flatMap { group ->
        val traceId1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString() // for clarity, two traceId
        Flux.deferContextual {
            Mono.just(it.get<String>("traceId2")) //for clarity, two traceId
        }.flatMap { traceId2 ->
            group.bufferTimeout(2, Duration.ofMillis(10))
                .concatMap {
                    // here I handle my batch
                    Mono.just(it).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(50))
                }.flatMap {
                    // and here I will commit
                    println("$it - $traceId1 - $traceId2")
                    Mono.just(it)
                }
        }
            .contextWrite {
                it.put("traceId2", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            }
    }
    .blockLast()

Every batch poll will have its own traceId.
The outout is:
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8] - 0e42ebe5-2f59-49b4-9ee2-1d42708ecc70 - dd007120-b544-4d8c-b9aa-059cda8a4d53
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9] - a7a9d1c0-9d3c-4cda-9e43-aac0c86940a1 - ab82ae64-e512-4476-b2f3-1ccf3b15803c
[11, 13, 15, 17, 19] - 8cc98954-4e48-44eb-803a-8b243e0c6244 - 8e515381-16c0-4cb4-8923-0703397971e9
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18] - e3707e39-5b92-4289-93ef-a76104bf036f - 384fe34e-fb6b-4d8a-8261-52f2294f618c
[20, 22, 24, 26, 28] - f82d0776-cf15-4850-9c9c-1d4374f0a36e - bfbca427-5177-4c21-9da9-7182ac6ef6ad
[21, 23, 25, 27, 29] - f364f43c-584b-461b-9a4c-8874aa7c6327 - f89a6ffc-db12-4462-ba05-1fd4482785d4
[30, 32, 34, 36, 38] - ef0b8b7d-9ae4-4d1c-8567-0441a514a6f1 - 27aaeb7b-4866-43da-8b3c-0640ed53bf66
[31, 33, 35, 37, 39] - 6a7218cb-3173-432d-9d48-fa8459b5d6c0 - ba3fa6d8-3491-4e38-b8b0-f2540432a3a6

